# How to make Mac Safari able to access fonts hosted in CDN (Azure)?

Tags: fonts, safari, azure-cdn

Users using Mac Safari are not able to access our site because Safari tries indefinitely to download fonts hosted in CDN (Azure) but never able to succeed. It was able to download all other files from the same CDN except fonts (woff, specified with @font-face).

All other browsers work
* Chrome (even those on the same Mac that has the above problem)
* FF, IE,
* Safari on iPhone/iPad

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a Cross Origin Resource Sharing problem. A CORS header inserted in the response will specify which domains are allowed to access this resource.

For Example:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com, http://www.contoso.com

You can fix this by changing your origin to send this header for the domains you want to allow (if you want to allow all, *), or use the Rules Engine within the Azure CDN with Verizon **Premium** Profile to add a rule to add this from the CDN.

You can find step by step instructions on how to do this here:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-cors/#multiple-origin-scenarios